# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function rrd_info()

Tags: php, rrdtool, undefined-function

I just installed rrdtool for php on Centos with `yum install php-rrdtool`.

I can run `php -m` and I can see `rrdtool` listed in the output. rrdtool support is successfully loaded, however, when I try to use any of the RRDTool functions in PHP, it fails with the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function rrd_info()
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function rrd_xport()
```

It looks like it hasn't been loaded...

What am I doing wrong? Everything seems OK to me...

Comment: Are you getting this error from the cli as well as from a webserver?

Comment: Yes.PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function rrd_info() in /usr/share/cacti/api2.php on line 35

Fatal error: Call to undefined function rrd_info() in /usr/share/cacti/api2.php on line 35

Comment: From command line as well? I only ask because some distros have separate ini files for webserver and command line... php -m states that it's there... are you sure it's being loaded for the webserver as well?

Comment: Apologies. Yes, it is being included in php_info(); on the webserver and also listed in the command line php -m.

Comment: So, rrd_graph() works, but none of the other functions work. Any ideas?